# How to get from Madurai to Munnar

Tags: india

I am going from Madurai to Munnar. I have searching information and have found that there are public buses, but I didn't manage to find any information about bus station and schedule.

I will be thankful for any additional information: how can I find the bus station, what is the schedule, how often the buses is going and so on.

Comment: Did you try rome2rio? (https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Madurai/Munnar) - it shows the options, and links to the bus schedules.

Comment: It gives only strange cycle route (10 hours), but I have read about direct route in the many places.

Comment: @Aganju, for example: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-still-a-bus-direct-from-Madurai-to-Munnar-from-Arappalayam